# Gwt elemental2: How can I convert between a gwt JavaScript object, and a JsInterop object?

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop, gwt-elemental

Lets say I have a `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document gwtDocument` node and I want to convert it to a `elemental2.dom.Document`?

Since Document extends JavaScriptObject I assumed I could do something like:

```
elemental2.dom.Document elementalDoc = (elemental2.dom.Document)(gwtDocument);
```

However the elemental2 classes using jsinterop don't extend JavaScriptObject. So how do I convert between the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can first cast to object, and then cast to the elemental type (1). This is a bit ugly, so there is a utility lib that can be used in GWT and J2CL called [jsinterop-base](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.jsinterop%22%20AND%20a%3A%22base%22). The `Js` utility can be used to `cast`(2) and `uncheckedCast`(3) any object. The `uncheckedCast` should be avoided and only used if you know what you are doing (ex. casting between iframes, or other special js situations).

```
com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document gwtDocument = Document.get();
elemental2.dom.Document el1 = (elemental2.dom.Document) (Object) gwtDocument; //(1)
elemental2.dom.Document el2 = jsinterop.base.Js.cast(gwtDocument); //(2)
elemental2.dom.Document el3 = jsinterop.base.Js.uncheckedCast(gwtDocument); //(3)
```

So in client code, you should use `Js.cast` to cast `GWT` dom instances to `elemental2` instances.